# Check if values in multiple columns are not null in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
       A        B        C
0    NaN      NaN   lizard
1    NaN  penguin  giraffe
2  horse   turtle      NaN
```

What I want to do is add a column (D) whose value is either that of column A *if it exists* otherwise it should be a combination of values in column B *and* C providing they are *both* not null/none. If column A is null and either of B or C is null, then D should be null/none.

I can do as such in regards to column A by using numpy's where function as such:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df['A'].notnull, df['A'], np.nan)
```

However I don't know how I would also add this column if *both* B and C aren't null/none.

Ideally the data frame would then look like this:

```
       A        B        C               D
0    NaN      NaN   lizard             NaN
1    NaN  penguin  giraffe  penguingiraffe
2  horse   turtle      NaN           horse
```

Comment: Your `np.where` approach is fine if you replace `np.nan` with `df["B"]+df["C"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat the columns `B` and `C`, then fill the `NaN` values in column `A` and assign this result to column `D`

```
df['D'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'] + df['C'])
```

---

```
       A        B        C               D
0    NaN      NaN   lizard             NaN
1    NaN  penguin  giraffe  penguingiraffe
2  horse   turtle      NaN           horse
```